# Open data set to calculate the correlation between different brands

Tags: data-request, tool-request

Is there any data sets / methods available to find correlation between different 'bands' ?

Brands : Puma, Google, Microsoft, Nike, BMW etc

Is there any open data set available to find this correlation ?
Also what are the different attributes/ methods that can be used to find correlation between them ?

eg : Nike is similar to Adidas with score say 0.9 (fitness brands)
     Nike is similar to Levis with score say 0.3 (apparels brands)
     Nike is similar to Google with score say 0.0 (different industry)

Comment: What do you mean by `correlation between different bands`?

Comment: Compare the brands' products. See how similar _they_ are, collectively.

Comment: If the question is about finding data to use, then this *might* be the correct site ... if it's about methods to find correlation between the data, datascience.SE (where you originally posted it to) would've been the better place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clarify your question, maybe giving more details about the application. There are many different ways a brand can be similar (or correlated) to another one, for example:

1. Correlation of stock trends. In this case, dataset can be found in yahoo finance, for example.
2. "Product Space" Analysis
3. By clustering features of each company

Comment: thanks, do you know any source from where I can get some sample data for clustering features ?

Comment: For US companies, for example, you can try http://www.opendata500.com/us/list/. Even though, the data available may not be enough to your study.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for [semantic similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity). The [normalized Google distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Google_distance) should be a good place to start, and gives the kind of [0-1] rating you are looking for.

> The Normalized Google Distance is a semantic similarity measure
>   derived from the number of hits returned by the Google search engine
>   for a given set of keywords.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) Keywords with the same or similar
>   meanings in a natural language sense tend to be "close" in units of
>   Normalized Google Distance, while words with dissimilar meanings tend
>   to be farther apart.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Google_distance